# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{r=k+1}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+1}{r} = 2^{2n}$

Tags: summation

I am trying to show:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{r=k+1}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+1}{r} = 2^{2n}$$

Could I have a hint?

I have tried rewriting $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{r=k+1}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+1}{r} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+1}{r}  $

but I'm not sure what to do next. I can't flip the sums because one is dependent on the dummy variable of the other. I have looked through Concrete Mathematics for a suitable identity but cannot find one that applies. I have also thought about how I could split the double sum into a product of sums, but I cannot quite see it.

Comment: Another duplicate is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350008/prove-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n1-sum-limits-m-0k-1-binomn1?noredirect=1), or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385622/i-cannot-prove-that-sum-k-0n-sum-i-kn-n-choose-k-n1-choose-i1?noredirect=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks. Feel free to close this then. I find it hard to search mathematical formulae...

Comment: @Oliver Always try searching on Approach0.xyz

Comment: @Nothingspecial Thanks! Didn't know this existed

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is good. Just go one step further: $\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{r=k+1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+1}{r}=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+1}{r}=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{r=0}^{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+1}{r}$ $k$ (First replace $r$ with $n+1-r$, then $k$ with $n-k$).
Then $\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{r=k+1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+1}{r}+\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{r=0}^{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+1}{r}=2^n2^{n+1}$.